# Does Azure Policy need to be in a separate JSON template or can it exist in a main JSON template?

Tags: json, azure, cloud

Usually in an ARM Infrastructure as Code, there is a main JSON and a parameters JSON. Trying to figure out if the Azure Policy needs to be in a separate JSON template or can it exist in a main JSON template?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Policy definition is just another resource in the ARM engine:

```
{
    "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions",
    "name": "allowed-role-definitions-def",
    "apiVersion": "2018-03-01",
    "properties": {
        "policyType": "Custom",
        "displayName": "Allowed Role Definitions",
        "description": "This policy defines a white list of role deifnitions that can be used in IAM",
        "mode": "all",
        "parameters": {
            "roleDefinitionIds": {
            "type": "array",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The list of role definition Ids",
                "displayName": "Approved Role Definitions"
                }
            }
        },
        "policyRule": {
            "if": {
                "allOf": [
                    {
                        "field": "type",
                        "equals": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments"
                    },
                    {
                        "not": {
                            "field": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/roleDefinitionId",
                            "in": "[parameters('roleDefinitionIds')]"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "then": {
                "effect": "deny"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this has to a be a subscription level deployment (not resource group).

https://blog.tyang.org/2018/06/06/using-arm-templates-to-deploying-azure-policy-definitions-that-requires-input-parameters/

Comment: What I really am trying to achieve, is an hierarchical JSON policy where this section: 

    "roleDefinitionIds": { "type": "array", "metadata": { "description": "The list of role 
    definition Ids", "displayName": "Approved Role Definitions" } } 

to be in a different file down in the resources - each resource to have its own JSONB param section file.

Comment: sorry, I do not follow

Comment: I have multiple resources, andI want to apply a policy for each of them. I want them all to have a single "Parent" JSON policy file, but parameter settings to be in separate files, same as the parameter ID. Otherwise I would have a giant main JSON file.

Comment: yeah, why not. assignment is just a resource in ARM, so you can create multiple resources on type `Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments` from the same parent template. just need to parametrize it properly